# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Test notification working, Scheduled one not

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have successfully sent and received a test notification through Firebase Messaging but when I actually schedule a notification it does not appear at all in my notification tray, the firebase console says status is Completed. Has anyone else had this issue?